# Main Flash swf won't work once uploaded to server

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs4

I have a 1 frame main SWF. In the first frame I include codeAS2.as like so:

`#include "codeAS2.as"` (sorry, might sound primitive)

When I test the movie in Flash CS4, everything works fine, it loads all the data from the XML file `menu.xml` which is in the same folder. Using the Simulate Download function from Flash, it also runs fine, with not one error, everything loads.

Now comes the headscratcher, once I upload it and run it, it does not work. The server is a Linux box and I work on a Mac.

Everything I load externally is in the same folder as the SWF, so I have no absolute paths, all relative to the SWF. Can this be some sort of sandbox issue?

Here is the url: [virleo(underscore)new.html](http://toolboxstudio.co.za/virleo2/virleo_new.html)
SWF: [virleo(underscore)new.swf](http://toolboxstudio.co.za/virleo2/virleo_new.swf)
Code: [codeAS2.as (inline code)](http://toolboxstudio.co.za/virleo2/codeAS2.as) and [Menu.as (class)](http://toolboxstudio.co.za/virleo2/Menu.as)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question like yours was answered many times. I remember one yesterday. I don't have link but you should change one option. Look after it in File>Publish Settings.. Should appear window. Go to "Flash" tab and change "Local playback security" option to "Access network only". Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Look after it in File>Publish Settings.. Should appear window. Go to "Flash" tab and change "Local playback security" option to "Access network only". Should work.

but doesn't

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.